# How to pass self to another class in iOS

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have to create a button multiple times on different ViewControllers and add the event to it. What i have done i created a class to handle them. I pass my UINavigationController to it and add a button to it. but nothing happens. i mean the button doesn't display. i call my Util class like

```
  MyUtil *util = [[MyUtil alloc];
 [util initWithNavAndAddBackButton:self.NavigationController];
```

// now it should display my custom back button which i have created but it is not displayed.

// i have passed nav by value and add a button to it but don't know why it is not showing it.

**MyUtil.h**

```
-(void)initWithNavAndAddBackButton:(UINavigationController *)nav;
```

**MyUtil.m**

```
-(void)initWithNavAndAddBackButton:(UINavigationController *)nav
{


 UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

//  `[btn setTarget:self action:@selector(popView:) forControlEventTouchUPInside];`
       // how can i pass self(Context in Android) that for which activity it is calling for

```
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,36,20);

UIBarButtonItem *barbtn = [[UIBarButton alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];

nav.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barbtn;
}


-(void) popView:(UINavigationController *)nav
{
[nav popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

**Problems i have**

First i have pass `UINaviagation` and add the `UIBarbutton` to it but it is not displaying .When I write the same code in each ViewController class . it is running accurately. I simply want to do this in a seperate class like a handler.

And i also want to push and pop in that activity. How can i pass self that or i mean how does this class knows the target that for which class this action belongs to. How can i pass the event for the ViewContoller.

Comment: If you are able to see the button, then do this: `[btn setTarget:nav action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:) forControlEventTouchUPInside];`

Comment: nav.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barbtn; this statement does this @croyneaus4u

Comment: Button is not displayed and can you told me what does target:nav means. I also want to do some other nav stuff. like pushView

Comment: `nav` means nothing, it is just the controller that you have passed as a parameter in your method. The `addTarget:` method adds a target (which I have mad as `nav`) for the button, which will execute the specified selector, since `nav` is a `navigationController`, I added the `popViewControllerAnimated:` method as selector which will be targeted on the navigationController :)

Comment: Thanks @croyneaus4u i understand this concept

Comment: You should not be setting the `leftBarButtonItem` on the `navigationController`'s `navigationItem`.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning your navigation controller instance to ViewController from MyUtil.

**MyUtil.h**

```
-(UIBarButtonItem *)initWithNavAndAddBackButton();
```

**MyUtil.m**

```
-(UIBarButtonItem *)initWithNavAndAddBackButton()
{
 UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,36,20);

 UIBarButtonItem *barbtn = [[UIBarButton alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
 return barbtn;
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
 MyUtil *util = [[MyUtil alloc];
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [util initWithNavAndAddBackButton:self.NavigationController];
```

Because when you pass an object, it is not passed by reference.

Comment: what about the `target` and `selector` ?? we dont need that ?

Comment: i also want to add event in MyUtil to push and pop. tell me how to add event to MyUtil and also tell me how to pass by reference like c with &variable with ** and then i don't want to return UINavigation .Correct

Comment: When i change the return type to UINavigationController it gives me an error Init methods must return a type related to the reciever type

Comment: by replacing the starting word init remove the error

Comment: Assign to readonly property error while assigning self.NavigationController = [util initWithNavAndBackButton:self.NavigationController]

Comment: Oh sorry, Updating my ans it should be UIBarButtonItem which is going to be created on the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyUtil *util = [[MyUtil alloc];
[util initWithNavAndAddBackButton:self.NavigationController];
```

Should be

```
MyUtil *util = [[MyUtil alloc] init];
[util initWithNavAndAddBackButton:self.NavigationController];
```

You are used with Android. In iOS is diffrent.

`self.navigationController` takes care of pushing and pop viewcontrollers

If you want a custom button to be used everywhere you can use the delegate method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
   if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
   {
       // Get reference to the destination view controller
      YourViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

       // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
      [vc setMyButtonHere:button];
   }
}
```

Comment: init is necessary and i am not using storyboard. I know navigationController takes care of it but tell me . what is my mistake there

Comment: you don't need to pass the navigationController.. you will have it anyway if it's a segue between viewcontrollers. just call self.navigationController

Comment: found this: http://storage.chrisrisner.com/images/ios-view-controllers-with-arrows.jpg it's an example that the controller is declared at the begining and takes care about navigation between view controllers

Answer (score 0):

**MyUtil.m**

```
+ (void)setNavigationItem:(UINavigationItem *)navItem forViewController:(UIViewController *)controller
{  
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_back.png"];
    UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image
                                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain     
                                                            target:controller 
                                                            action:@selector(popView)];
    navItem.leftBarButtonItem = item;
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
[MyUtil setNavigationItem:self.navigationItem forViewController:self];

- (void)popView
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```